# How to mask password with MaterialTable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MaterialTable and want to mask a column values but I,m not able to do so.

Can you please help?

I am using MaterialTable to show users for an app.

```
import MaterialTable from "material-table";

function UserProfile() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    columns: [
      { title: "Logging Name", field: "name" },
      {
        title: "password",
        field: "password",
      }
],

data: [
      {
        name: "Dan",
        password: "TopseCrets@1"
}]

return (
    <div style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
      <MaterialTable
        title="User List"
        columns={state.columns}
        data={state.data}
.
.
.
);



I want to see ***** instead of password for the corresponding field, password string should be displayed only when I try to edit the row.
```

Answer (score 1):

At this time, material-table doesn't have support for a custom password field.

I was able to salvage the solution on https://gitter.im/material-table/Lobby?at=5ebbf9c82cf0da0ad9fda27c (the chat lobby of material-table)

In short for your password column, you want to add additional properties (render, and editComponent):

```
        { 
        title: 'Password', field: 'password',
        render: rowData => <p>{rowData.password.split('').map(() => '*')}</p>,
        editComponent: props => (
            <TextField
                type="password"
                value={props.value}
                onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
            />)
        },
```

render property will replace characters when displaying the field.

editComponent will use your own TextField component, with type "password" to hide the value when editing the row.